# My double is being rounded

Tags: double

Okay, so I have a this equation here that's suppose to get close to the value of pi, but for some reason, my double value is always being converted to a whole number. For example, one of my number is 1/3 but when I print it out, it becomes 0.0. Is it because you have to add d to the end of double values? If so, how would I add it to the end of something like this:

fractionpart = fractionpart + (1/i)

Comment: What is the data type of i? If it's an integer that's why. Try fractionpart = fractionpart +(1.0/i)

Answer (score 1):

A `D` is not used for double constants in C, they are double by default, but a `.` is. That is, `1` is an integer, while `1.` is a double (`1.F` is a float, BTW, and 1.L is a long double, if it is supported by your compiler).

I personally prefer to add a `0` after the `.` because `1.` looks like the end of an English sentence, while `1.0` looks like a proper number. The leading 0 is also optional, so you can write for example `.1`, but I prefer `0.1`.

So your calculation can be written as:

```
fractionpart = fractionpart + 1.0 / i;
```

The alternative would be to add a cast to make the type explicit:

```
fractionpart = fractionpart + 1 / (double)i;
```

You can cast any of the two operands of the division.